# Insert Into Existing Table with Complexities

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to copy some info from a table that has been set up properly into another table that is being configured. The table in question stores settings for users as recognised by their Active Directory user (for the program that is accessing the database).

I can't just copy the table across because there are different users in each table with different settings. I am only concerned with a specific criteria.

The table is set up with the following columns:
SeqNum
User
Data1
Data2
Data3
Data4

SeqNum and User will be different between tables and the rows will need to be new, not modifying existing. What I want to do is insert new rows with the next available SeqNum and a SPECIFIED user (that I can specify) and then copy the columns Data1-Data4 into their respective columns. The number of rows to be inserted will vary. Does anyone have a suggestion on the best way to achieve this? I don't think I can do a simple insert into becuase that won't account for the variable in SeqNum and User.

To make this a little clearer, I have attached an image showing an example of Table 1 and Table 2 with the addition of the three new lines in Table 2.

Hopefully this sort of makes sense. There will be hundreds of lines and dozens of users that this will need to be done to.

T.I.A.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0VtH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved with a simple INSERT INTO, but the two issues you point to must be solved:;

- how to compute the seqno when inserting
- how to replace the username when inserting

While an [identity column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) / autoincrement column could solve the need for the seqno, I assume schema changes is not what you are looking for. I would combine a subquery selecting the current max value for seqno with [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to compute the value, something like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SeqNum) + (SELECT MAX(SeqNum) FROM Table2) AS SeqNum
```

As for replacing the username with something you set manually, it all depends on how you want to execute this. If a manual query satisfies your needs, it can be as easy as setting a set string in your query like:

```
'ManuallySetUserName' AS [User]
```

Combining this into a query would yield:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (SeqNum, [User], Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SeqNum) + (SELECT MAX(SeqNum) FROM Table2) AS SeqNum,
  'ManuallySetUserName' AS [User],
  Data1, 
  Data2, 
  Data3, 
  Data4
FROM Table1
WHERE [SomeCondition...];
```

Assuming the condition for copying as all settings row for a given username, you could wrap this in a stored procedure, adding input parameters for the username to copy and the username to set, along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyUserSettings (@UserNameFrom varchar(200), @UserNameTo varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table2 (SeqNum, [User], Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SeqNum) + (SELECT MAX(SeqNum) FROM Table2) AS SeqNum,
      @UserNameTo AS [User],
      Data1, 
      Data2, 
      Data3, 
      Data4
    FROM Table1
    WHERE [User] = @UserNameFrom
END
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abeaa)

Comment: You da man...Thanks for this. This will be fine. I just couldn't get my head around what I was trying to do for some reason. Thanks again for your assistance.